# SpriteKit convertPoint:toNode: throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, memory, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

I have the following code extract within a function (ARC):

```
-(CGFloat)getRotationAngleFromJoint:(BAJoint*)from_joint toJoint:(BAJoint*)to_joint {
    // Here we basically have a node graph where joints are connected by bones.
    // In this case we have these connections: from_joint -> from_bone -> from_joint2
    //
    // BAJoint and BABone both derived classes of SKShapeNode

    __weak BABone *from_bone = (BABone*)[from_joint.children objectAtIndex:0];
    __weak BAJoint *from_joint2 = (BAJoint*)[from_bone.children objectAtIndex:0];

    CGPoint k = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    CGPoint p1 = [from_joint2 convertPoint:k toNode:from_joint.parent];
```

BAJoint is declared thus:

```
@interface BAJoint : SKShapeNode <NSCoding, NSCopying>

@property BOOL rootJoint;

-(void)setRootJoint;
-(void)select;
-(void)deselect;

@end
```

***from_joint2***, ***from_joint***, ***from_joint.parent*** are all non-zero weak pointers, and yet I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the call to *convertPoint:toNode:*

I have confirmed that the weak pointers are pointing to valid memory by logging the ***position*** iVar, e.g., ***from_joint.position*** and a sensible value is logged in these cases.  At least I presume a sensible value implies the pointer is pointing to a valid place in memory.

Enabling zombies doesn't show anything either and enabling exception breakpoints doesn't even catch this.

Any ideas why *convertPoint:toNode:* might throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?  What things might cause this error to occur in this particular case?

I would really appreciate any help on this as I've spent a LONG time looking at it.  I'm quite new to Objective-C.

**UPDATE**

After having read through some of the posts on StackOverflow, I have a sneaky suspicion that SKShapeNode is quite bugged and not to be trusted.  I got around my problem by replicating the subgraph with SKNode* instances and applying convertPoint:toNode: to SKNodes rather than SKShapeNodes.

In addition SKShapeNode seems to leak memory constantly and other posts here indicate the same.

Comment: What kind of objects are `from_joint2` and `from_joint`?

Comment: I've included the declaration for BAJoint above.  It;s basically an SKShapeNode with some small additions.

Comment: What is being stored in its `.children` array when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing interesting on the stack trace? (Xcode has a slider on the bottom to show the whole thing.)